# Browser page refresh gets a new session cookie/id

Tags: node.js, express, tedious

I am having this issue in my application. Whenever the browser refreshes it reassign the cookie with a new content and thus a new session id. It is the right behavior of a browser?

The application uses express and connect-tedious libraries of the nodejs. The user gets logged out because the cookie content and session id is now different whenever he does a refresh. Any suggestion on how to go about resolving this problem?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?  Usually a session id is created once, then used throughout the session, then disposed of when the user logs out or the cookie expires.

Comment: @kevin628 The code is in bits and pieces in different modules.. I dk which part to show u? And also I can only do it when i am back in office on Tue. U mean there could be sth wrong with the implementation that causes the cookies to be created with every page refresh?

Comment: Usually there's some piece of code whose responsibility is to get the current session or create one if it doesn't exist.  I'm thinking there might be code somewhere that is just continually recreating the session every time the user refreshes the browser.  It's a common mistake to make.  I make it all the time when building new applications.

Comment: U may take a look at this, our code is built on sth like this (look at the 2nd last piece of code): http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/ There is a new Session in the listener for the 'authorization' part.... but before the new session, the cookie is already different. We used a portion of the cookie content to obtain the session stored in the database. How come the cookie content is different after refresh? Do note that is only after login then refresh the cookie content will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your node server code that is responsible for setting the cookies for the user and the session (using the `Set-Cookie` header or generating a Javascript file for the client with the same), then it should also check for existing cookies in the request. When the page is reloaded, the request would come to your server again. At that point you can read the cookies that were passed to the server (which would include the cookie for session and user that were set the last time). If these cookies are found and are valid, the server should not generate a new cookie for the same.

Even if this logic does not reside on the server and is a part of your client side JS, the overall idea is the same. Do not create new cookies, if you can read the existing ones correctly.

Comment: I rmb we have a lot of checking for "req.cookies['express.sid']", not sure abt the Set-Cookie header part... What do u mean by "generating a Javascript file for the client with the same"? Will check again when i am back in office.

Comment: The you really need to post some code to get an idea what might be going wrong. The browser on its own cannot replace cookies. It has to be through some code you would have written. "generating a Javascript file for the client with the same" - a JS file which can set cookies using `document.cookie` could be an alternate way to set cookies.

Comment: Thanks, is really cos of the document.cookie